# Корни "-плав-" и "-плов-"

Tags: этимология, орфография

Почему в корне "-плав-" в слове "-пловчиха" **а** меняется на **о**? Чем это вызвано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ещё на "ы" в слове плывун. Чередование имеет историческое объяснение, которое выходит далеко за рамки обычныго школьного правила, в связи с которым обычно и задаётся этот вопрос.
Я попробую объяснить, но очень приблизительно, полное объяснение совершенно неподъёмное.

Это корневое чередование очень древнее, восходит к тем временам, когда общий предок славянских языков (иногда его называют протославянским) имел более развитую систему вокализмов: существовала развитая система дифтонгов и разделение гласных на долгие и краткие. При этом система ударений была принципиально отличной от современной. Так, место ударения могло выполнять смыслоразличительную функцию. Со временем во многих словах различия в месте ударения привело к различию и в качестве гласного, особенно это касалось А и О - под ударениями они стали произноситься как долгие, без ударения - как краткие.
На следующем этапе развития системы вокализмов, с исчезновением различий долгих и кратких, произошло на первый взгляд неожиданное превращение: долгие А и О рефлексировали в современное А, краткие А и О породили современное О. Следы этого процесса мы наблюдаем во многих русских корнях.  Однако в чередовании плов/плав/плыв он осложнился двумя факторами - гибкостью ударения (чередование плав/плов в современном языке не связано с ударностью гласного) и дополнительным влиянием формы "плавать" которое смешивалась с суффиксальными формами на "vati" приставочных глаголов несовершенного вида (разбить - разб**ивать**), хотя в пловец/плавать/плывун В - коренное, а не суффиксальное. Под влиянием этого смешения появилась "Ы" в корне плыть, плывун.

Answer (score 1):

Слова которые относятся к человеку пишутся с **о**, например: пловчиха, пловец.

Слова которые относятся к не одушевлённым предметам пишутся с **а**, например: поплавок, плавник.

Comment: Не кричите так, мы хорошо видим.

Comment: Вы отвечаете, как запомнить, а не почему!

Answer (score 1):

Двумя руками за чистоту русского языка, но совершенно против необъяснимых процессов. Объяснение от behemothus любопытно, однако следует либо возвращаться к протославянскому языку, либо адаптировать слова к современности. Меня не устраивает ответ "плОвец - словарное слово/исключение". "Плов" - это еда, а "пловец" - по-видимому, должен быть человек, любящий плов или умеющий его хорошо готовить. Самое неприятное в данной ситуации, что в третьем классе средней школы никто не способен дать ученику вразумительный ответ. Поверить на слово учителю? А вдруг получится ситуация сродни "корню из минус единицы", в школе такого не бывает "никогда в жизни", а в институте это "иррациональные числа". После такого доверие к процессу образования уменьшается.
С уважением. Хотелось бы увидеть комментарии заинтересованных лиц.

Comment: *<<После такого доверие к процессу образования уменьшается>>*

Школьное образование даёт упрощённое толкование, вполне достаточное для среднего образования. По моему скромному мнению, школьная программа и так перегружена разными подробностями, в общем-то не нужными рядовому человеку. Школа даёт основы, а в подробностях того или иного предмета может разобраться тот, кто будет на этом специализироваться. Ну или просто интересуется тем или иным делом.

Comment: Для разных задач необходима (и достаточна) разная точность. Например, упрощённо говоря, Земля имеет форму шара. Для того, чтобы сделать глобус, таких сведений достаточно. Если говорит точнее, то *"шар — геометрическое тело; совокупность всех точек пространства, находящихся от центра на расстоянии, не больше заданного."* На Земле есть низины и возвышенности и т.д. И в точности — Земля не совсем соответствует форме шара. Даже если считать только по уровню моря, то она немного сплюснута с полюсов. Для описания такой формы применяют особый термин — **геоид**.

Comment: Ну или могу привести, возможно более понятный пример. Контрольно-измерительные приборы. Для них нужна разная точность. Возьмем измерение длины, расстояния, как наиболее понятное обычному человеку.  Расстояние от вашего дома до школы, Вы, Дмитрий, не будете измерять в **сантиметрах**. Такие подробности, **в данном случае**, не имеют смысла. Подойдут метры или километры. А если прикинуть, сколько нужно ехать автомобилем до ближайшего города, то нужны будут километры. Несколько метров или, возможно, даже километров здесь уже роли не играют.

Answer (score 0):

О пишется только в словах пловец пловцы пловчиха пловчихи, в остальных пишется а исключение плывун